# Has AKP ever failed to pass any bill after losing majority in Turkish Parliament?

Tags: parliament, turkey

In the [2018 Turkish parliamentary election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Turkish_parliamentary_election), *Justice and Development Party (AKP)* won 295 seats out of 600 and lost majority in the Turkish Parliament. On the other hand, the *People's Alliance* they formed with *Nationalist Movement Party (MHP)* kept majority by 344 (295+49) seats.

I wonder if AKP were able to pass every bill they proposed since then. Of course there should be many bills that were not supported by all MPs of the party, but I'm looking for a case other parties surpassed AKP.

My web search (e.g. [akp's bill was rejected](https://www.google.com/search?q=akp%27s%20bill%20was%20rejected)) didn't return anything relevant.

Comment: Hard to prove the negative without a complete list of each bill and its results. Not sure if that exists but I'm not finding it English.

Comment: @BrianZ I have found a [query page](https://www.tbmm.gov.tr/develop/owa/tasari_teklif_sd.sorgu_baslangic) in Turkish, but couldn't figure out how to use it effectively.

Comment: On the general principles of parliamentary government, a loss on a bill which the majority does not declare a "free choice" bill would triggers a new election. But, since the post of Prime Minister was abolished effective after the 2018 election, it isn't clear that this rule still applies in Turkey.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/turkish-parliament-passes-penal-reform-law-153838

> The bill, introduced by the ruling Justice and Development Party (AKP) and Nationalist Movement Party (MHP), was supported by 279 lawmakers in the 600-seat chamber while 51 voted against it.

There you go.

Considering the passing of this bill, it seems to me that the AKP party has got some alliance, and many of the members abstained themselves from voting.

Comment: How did it pass with only 279/600 votes in favor? Did most of the opposition abstain/vote "present"?

Comment: @divibisan looks like both are true.

Comment: @divibisan Minimum 200 MPs are required to start a session, then 50% + 1 (can't be less than 151 in any case) votes have to be in favor.